# SMO issue on 64 bit

Tags: smo

I have a VB.NET application which is set to TargetCPU= x86. As part of installer, I install the x86 versions of the following SQL Management Objects, SQL Native Clients and SQl CLR Types on the customers machine and everything works fine. However if I have a 64 bit machine, and I install the 64 bit versions of these same packages, I get a "ExecuteNonQuery Failed" because "Microsoft.SMo.BatchParser.dll" was not found. So I tried installing the 32 bit versions of the packages, and only the SQL Management Objects x86 and SQL CLRTypes x86 installed successfully. The SQL Native Client x86 failed saying it was the wrong operating system. But now my  application worked without error. I am now confused as to what I need to deploy?!?!? The x86 versions or mix or all??